# Printing inside window, not on borders

Tags: c, ncurses

I'm trying to write something inside a curses window, but it seems to write on borders too. How can I fix the code below?

```
win_self = newwin(LINES / 2, COLS, 0, 0);
box(win_self, 0, 0);
wrefresh(win_self);
wprintw(win_self, "foobar");
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In curses, the borders generated by `box()` are *inside* borders. As far as I can tell, there's no way to simply say "don't overwrite my border".

Nevertheless, there are three solutions that I can think of right now:

- don't overwrite the border characters (use `move()`)
- draw the box *after* you draw window contents, then `refresh()` the screen (you're probably still overwriting something, but at least it's not the border characters)
- create a "border window" with borders and a "content window" inside of it, which of course starts at (border_window_start_y + 1, border_window_start_x + 1) and is two lines/columns smaller than the "border window"

Just to make it more clear: the `box()` function doesn't add the property "this window has visible borders" to the window, it just prints border characters around the window.

You are:

- free to overwrite those border characters
- supposed to be cautious if you don't want them overwritten

Comment: I Chose the third solution as a temporary hack. Now it seems that the hack is 'production code'.

Comment: Yep, I think it's the best possible solution.

Comment: Third one is really a good idea and i implemented it as well. But now i have a problem with multiple overlapping windows and panels. I assign the outer (border) window to the panel, but when i close (hide) a window the other window below get's not refreshed for the window not beeing assigned to the below panel ... is there a solution for this, too? maybe additional panels?

Comment: To answer my own question: yes, it seems to work when i use two panels (one for border, one for content).

Comment: I've like 3 days thinking how to bypass this and "create a "border window" with borders and a "content window"" was the perfect solution!!! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

I'd say the easiest way is to create a (content) window inside of the (borders) window and print in that inner window.

```
WINDOW *win_self = newwin(LINES / 2, COLS, 0, 0);
box(win_self, 0, 0);
WINDOW *derwin_self = derwin(win_self, LINES / 2 - 2, COLS - 2, 1, 1);
wprintw(derwin_self, "foobar");
```

Comment: Shouldn't the starting row and column of the derwin() be 1, 1 not 0, 0?