# Best gem for working with ncurses and ruby

Tags: ruby, ncurses

I am interested in creating a command line application with ruby that would require moderately complex interaction with the user. I would like to use ncurses for this.

What is the best gem for working with ruby and ncurses, or should I be using stdlib utilities in ruby?

Comment: Probably best to avoid "What is the best" questions. Still its a good question despite the rules.

Answer (score 16):

Ruby [includes bindings](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/curses/rdoc/index.html) for the `curses` library. Despite what the name implies, [it will use `ncurses`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/curses/curses.c#L22) if possible.

Third party libraries often provide abstractions on top of either Ruby's `curses` or their own bindings. For example, `ncursesw` also wraps the `panel`, `menu` and `form` extensions. When I worked with Ruby's `curses`, I created my own `Window` class with [proper border support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749634/printing-inside-window-not-on-borders).

If the basic methods are sufficient, I don't see any reason to add a dependency to your project. However, if you want to do fancy things more easily, you should use a library that provides support for what you need.

Comment: As of Ruby 2.1 curses has been removed from the standard library and is now available as an independently developed gem: http://rubygems.org/gems/curses

Answer (score 3):

I have found [`ncursesw`](http://rubygems.org/gems/ncursesw) on [this](http://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=curses) Rubygems seach. Seems to be a good gem to start with.

Comment: yes there are several gems available, but what do people think is the best?

Answer (score 2):

This one appears to have the best readme https://github.com/seanohalpin/ffi-ncurses