# Escape sequence for deleting next/trailing character?

Tags: ruby, escaping

Is it possible, in addition to deleting a leading character using `\x08`, to also delete a trailing character? Is there an escape sequence that will delete the next character instead of the previous one?

I see that delete is apparently mapped to ASCII 127, which is Hex 7F, but the following code:

```
puts "a\x08b\x7fcd"
```

produces

```
b⌂cd
```

I expected that \x7f would delete the 'c' character following it, but it does not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You aren't actually deleting anything with `\x08` , you are merely overwriting the "a" with a "b".

Imagine the very old days when you used a teletype paper terminal. What you would actually see on the paper is an "a" printed, the teletype would back up one space and then print a "b" over it. All the non-printing ascii codes were invented to control the movement of teletype paper terminals.

That's exactly what the output above does, only the terminal screen does not keep the pixels lit for the previous "a".

The "del" char does not have this special meaning to the basic terminal screen. It might mean something to a program such as an editor or a shell, but to STDOUT it's just another ascii char to print.

The original meaning of "del" is ignore this char as input, see :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_character

There is nothing I know of that you can put before a char that STDOUT will treat as a signal not to print the next CHAR. However if your output is to a terminal emulation program such as xterm, you can do many things using escape codes to accomplish what you want. See for example:

http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php

The "standard" library for abstracting out all these complex codes is `ncurses`, of which there are a couple ruby interfaces. see

[Best gem for working with ncurses and ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398076/best-gem-for-working-with-ncurses-and-ruby)

Comment: `echo -e 1'first\e7second\e8\e[Knew'`  # OUTPUTS firstnew using the save cursor position and restore cursor position

Comment: Awesome link @fred-the-magic-wonder-dog => Prettier than https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html

Answer (score 3):

The backspace character (charcode `?\x08`, its alias `?\b` and its frequent `?\C-H` (Ctrl+H) mapping) is not the same as the delete character (charcode `?\x7f`, meaning ascii 127). Out of the box, the difference between the two is that backspace moves the cursor position left before deleting.

Note that in both cases on unix platforms, deleting usually stands for the kill escape sequence, and that the latter stands for killing the line from the cursor right (i.e. like the Ctrl+K mapping in Terminal). Put another way, `?\b` is equivalent to `"\e[D\e[K"` (left, kill) and `?\x7f` is equivalent to `"\e[K"` (kill). Sample output in IRB (Ruby 2.0.0, OSX) to illustrate this:

```
>> print "abc\b"            # abc, backspace
ab=> nil
>> print "abc\e[D\b"        # abc, left, backspace
a=> nil
>> print "abc\x7f"          # abc, delete
abc=> nil
>> print "abc\e[D\x7f"      # abc, left, delete
ab=> nil
>> print "abc\e[D\e[D\x7f"  # abc, left, left, delete
a=> nil
>> print "abc\e[D\e[D\e[K"  # abc, left, left, kill
a=> nil
```

The operating word in the above is *usually*. If you play with getch in a terminal, the behavior will be quite different from that of IRB. (If memory serves, the delete key will then move the character left without killing the line, or something to that order.)

Getting back to your question with this clarified: to the best of my knowledge, there is no escape sequence to kill a single character at the cursor's position; only sequences to kill a line to the left, right, or both of the cursor. The reference posted by Fred is quite good in case you want to dive in:

http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php

At any rate, I'm guessing that you're playing with `getch` or something to that order. What you'd want to do, in order to delete a single character, is to maintain a buffer and the cursor's position at the same time as you're printing characters to stdout. This will allow you to map `?\b` or `?\x7f` as you see fit, using something like:

```
def refresh
  rest = @buffer[@position..-1]
  @stdout.print "\e[K"
  @stdout.print rest, "\e[#{rest.length}D" if rest && !rest.empty?
  nil
end
```

Alternatively, try the usual suspects to spare yourself the headaches: readline, ncurses, the highline gem, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is: standard `IO` has no short-term memory. That says there is no magic operating entity to act on *forthcoming* symbols. The following code snippet shows that “delete,” even supplied with a [modern way](http://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termutils-2.0/html_chapter/tput_1.html), has no clue about symbols from the future:

```
> puts "a#{`tput dch1`}b"
# ⇒ ab
```

Whether you really need to “delete prospective symbol,” I would suggest you to use plain ruby monkeypatch for that:

```
class String
  DEL = '␡'
  def postprocess
    self.gsub /#{DEL}./, ''
  end
end

puts "a␡bc".postprocess
# ⇒ ac
```

Actually, this is not an answer directly to your question, but it might give a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative approach to deleting the next character:

```
class String
  alias_method :default_initialize, :initialize
  alias_method :default_plus, :+

  attr_accessor :delnext

  def initialize
    default_initialize
    @delnext = false
  end

  def +(x)
    str = String(x)
    str[0] = '' if @delnext
    @delnext = false
    default_plus str
  end
end
```

Now, you can do:

```
s = 'test string'
s.delnext = true
s += 'test again'
s # => 'test stringest again'
```

Similarly, you can easily implement `delprev`:

```
class String
  def delprev
    self[self.length - 1] = ''
    # self # uncomment if you want delprev to return the new string
  end
end

s = 'test string'
s.delprev
s # => 'test strin'
```